# NameError: name 'util' is not defined in sentence bert

Tags: python, bert-language-model, transformer-model

after installing sentence bert with following command

```
!pip install -U sentence-transformers
```

I used this code

```
util.http_get('http://sbert.net/datasets/simplewiki-2020-11-01.jsonl.gz', wikipedia_filepath)
```

getting following error

NameError: name 'util' is not defined

Comment: Seems you haven't imported `util` from somewhere then?

Comment: have u imported util in the python script?

Comment: Please add your complete code.